# Limiting the number of basic authentication attempts in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, http-basic-authentication

I'm using HTTPS + Basic authentication to protect a resource. How can I throttle authentication attempts to protect against brute force attacks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

install fail2ban and enable rules for apache